# Laravel: Queueing mails with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I want to queue mails as explained at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#queueing-mail.

This is what I did so far:

1. I changed `QUEUE_DRIVER` in the `.env` file

   ```
   QUEUE_DRIVER=database
   ```
2. I created a [job table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#driver-prerequisites)

   ```
   php artisan queue:table
   php artisan migrate
   ```

I add a mail to the queue like this:

```
Mail::to($request->user())
    ->queue(new OrderShipped($order));
```

I setup a cronjob that will send the queried mails as explained in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#defining-schedules) like this:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('php artisan queue:work --once')->everyMinute();
}
```

If I would only write `$schedule->command('php artisan queue:work')->everyMinute();` then the work process would never stop, so the server would be very busy at some point having a lot of parallel working processes, right?

Did I miss anything important in order to query mails with laravel? Also if I would like to send every minute at most 5 mails - how could I achieve that?

Comment: database is not a real Queue driver. Beanstalkd or IronQueue is better option.

Comment: @LeventeOtta I only send about 10-200 emails per day. I think using a database is atm perfectly fine. Or would there be any advantage that I am missing when using IronQueue?

Comment: You are run a command 1440/day and it just work 10-200 times per day. ~1200 commands loads the server daily.

Comment: @LeventeOtta well thats fine with my server.. I am worried when I get more then 10000 request per second. The one artisan request can be ignored. At least I don't see a point in paying for a service starting from 5$ a week just to reduce the number of request per second by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of cron job, it is better to set up a supervisor configuration. It will help to monitor the queue jobs. It can be easily configured by using the following documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: Why would I need that? Monitoring all jobs that were not send can be easily displayed by `php artisan queue:failed` . What would be the benefit of supervisior?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of starting every minute the command

```
php artisan queue:work --once
```

its better to start the work queue once and add a sleep timer:

```
php artisan queue:work --sleep=60
```

this would do one job every minute. If one wants to do 5 jobs every minute once can reduce the sleeping time:

```
php artisan queue:work --sleep=12
```